# Why do people say "X happened 100 times, and there is a 1/100 chance of Y happening after X, so Y must have already happened"?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I often hear people use this as an argument: An event has a 1/X chance of happening in a situation and that situation already happened X times, so the event already happened at least once.

But I don't understand how this is true. If the probability of the event happening is $\frac{1}{n}$, the probability of it not happening is $(1 - \frac{1}{n})$, so the probability of it not happening n times is $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$ and the probability of it happening at least once is $1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$.

Not only this is not equal to $1$ for any $n$, the limit of it as $n$ approaches infinity converges to $1 - \frac{1}{e}$, which is just about 63%.

Comment: Most people don't understand probability as well as you do.  The probability of x happening in x times is about 63% as you argued.

Comment: You may want to ask these people how it is possible to get two heads in a row when flipping a coin when the probability of getting tails is 50%... If they are not convinced then perhaps you have a very profitable gambling opportunity.

Comment: They are trivial beings delivered by the SF to annoy you.

Comment: "so the probability of it not happening n times is $1−(1−1/n)^n$" .  I think you skipped the middle of the sentence.  I think you meant: "so the probability of it not happening n times $(1-1/n)^n$ and the probability of it happening at least once is $1−(1−1/n)^n$"

Comment: I don't agree with the way this post was edited. There was a mistake in the post that was addressed in my post. This makes my answer sound like nonsense. There are many questions with wrong statements on this website. The standard approach is to address those mistakes in the answers, not just editing the post. Is there any reason to be so sure that a mistake in a post is due to a typo? or the OP just has skipped a sentence?

Comment: **Patient:** "Doc, what are my chances?" **Doctor:** "You have nothing to worry about. Nine out of ten people who get this disease die, but I've had nine patients already and they all died."

Comment: @msm: I edited the post. I had accidentally typed the wrong thing without thinking.

Comment: As the post was originally written msm's answer made sense.  But we can't fault an op for correcting his/her own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is exactly correct, assuming the individual trials are independent. The belief that an event with low probability ($1/n$) is bound to occur after $n$ trials is a version of the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy), the belief that there is some kind of compensatory force that increases the probability of the event the longer you've waited without seeing the event. People who believe this may be inclined to justify this by multiplying $1/n$ by $n$ to obtain a value of $1$.

(Of course this compensatory force has to be balanced against the belief in a *sustaining* force that encourages hot streaks to remain hot. :)

Answer (score 0):

They aren't right. They think they can add the probabilities but they can't.

Comment: I remember a fast food sweepstakes the published your odds of winning if you bought 1 to 6 items.  e.g.  winning the 1,000,000 with 1 purchase was 1 - 3,456,786 with 2 purchases 1- 1728393 etc. and I realized they were just adding the prob.  The odds of wining a burger were 1-6 with 1 purchase. 1-3 with 2, 1-2 with 3, 2-3 with 6, 5-6 with 5, and 1-1 with 6.  To win a drink it was 1-4 with 1.  1-2 with 2, 3-4 with 3, 1-1 with 4 and "more than 1 in 1 chance" for 5 or 6 purchases.  I really wondered what they thought "more than 1 in 1 chance" could possibly mean.